# How do I run a command as the user and not root in my recipe?

Tags: git, yocto

**Minimal version of my problem :**

Let's say I want to include in my image a file containing the name of the user who built it. I'd write something like `whoami > ${D}/path/to/the/file` in a recipe and hope for the best.

In practice, the file always contains `root` and not the name of the user, so my question is : how can I run `whoami` from within my recipe as the actual user?

**Actual use case :**

The thing I'm actually trying to do is a bit different but boils down to the same issue.
My project is structured like this :

```
myproject
- menu.json
- layers
| - poky
| - meta-foo
| - meta-bar
- builds
  - downloads
  - sstate
  - build-directory
```

This structure is not created manually, but automatically through [Yocto cooker](https://github.com/cpb-/yocto-cooker) : the `menu.json` file lists every information needed for repeatable builds. The `myproject` directory is a git repository versioning that file, which amounts to versioning the entire project. The tool reads the file and handles cloning/updating the correct layers (kind of like what you would do with google repo or git submodules), generating the build directory, adding what I want to the `local.conf` file, and launching the build.

What I actually want to do is to include version info in my image, so basically running `git describe --tags` in `myproject` and in each layer's directory, then storing the result in a file.
Those directories belong to the user, so running the command as root results in `git: fatal: detected dubious ownership` errors. I have found a dirty workaround (running `git config --global --replace-all safe.directory '*'` beforehand), but I'm looking for a clean solution, i.e. running the command as the actual user

Comment: You can disable pseudo (Yocto's fakeroot-like application) with `PSEUDO_DISABLED=1`. E.g. if you run `PSEUDO_DISABLED=1 whoami`, it will give your current username.